Isolate repository subdirectory into a separate branch
How do I break a subdirectory from main and push it onto a new branch (preferrably without disturbing the history of main in the process)? I don't really care about the sub history.
Currently I have this:
-------main: ./foo
             ./dist/bar1
             ./dist/bar2

I want this:
-------main: ./foo

-------dist: ./bar1
             ./bar2

The ./dist/ folder is generated at runtime so I don't want that to be on main at all. My goal is to have this whole process done in a .yaml. dist will only get commit through this.
I tried cloning the dist branch to the folder acting as another unrelated repository but when I try to cd dist to run the git commands, the git context is stuck in main and it pushes the entire main root to dist.
I also tried doing git subtree but that is throwing an error: fatal: no new revisions were found.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository git subtree is the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+detach+subdirectory What errors do you have with it?

Does this answer your question? Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository

@JimRedmond When I try that I get "fatal: no new revisions were found"

@phd When I try that I get "fatal: no new revisions were found"
